# rails json response with gzip compression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, gzip, rack

I have an api written in rails which on each request responds with a JSON response.

The response could be huge, so i need to compress the JSON response using gzip.

Wondering how to do this in rails controller?

I have added the line

```
use Rack::Deflater
```

in config.ru

Should I also be changing something in the line which renders JSON?

```
render :json => response.to_json()
```

Also, how do i check if the response is in gzip format or not..??

I did a curl request from terminal, I see only the normal plain JSON.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the response to be in gzip format we don't have to change the `render` method call.
If the request has the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, Rails will automatically compress the JSON response using gzip.

If you don't want the user to send a request with preset header., you can add the header to the request manually in the controller before rendering the response:

```
request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] = 'gzip'
render :json => response.to_json()
```

Comment: Confirming @curiousmind's response below - you also have to add the `Rack::Deflater` middleware to get Rails to compress the JSON response, _even if_ you have passed the Accept-Encoding request header in set to 'gzip,deflate'. Note that the request header is also required for compression to kick in.

Answer (score 37):

My post [Content Compression with Rack::Deflater](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/content-compression-with-rack-deflater/) describes a couple of ways to integrate Rack::Deflater. The easiest would be to just update `config/application.rb` with:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
  end
end
```

and you'll automatically compress all controller responses with deflate / gzip if the client explicitly says they can handle it.

Comment: I needed this Rack Middleware declaration as well as the headers to get a gzip response. Thanks!

Comment: I add `config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater` to application.rb, compression start working only on Mac OS (Chrome, FF and Safary). On windows I receive responses without 'Content-Encoding: gzip;' in FF and IE (works only in chrome). P.S. "Accept-Encoding: gzip" present in all browsers. Do you know why?)

Comment: @bmalets Does this still happen? Found a way around this?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, as I remember, it was a problem of old FF and IE browsers and I fixed this problem by enabling gzipping in  nginx configurations

Comment: @bmalets Do you remember the versions of FF and IE you are referring to? About adding gzipping in nginx configurations. Is it something along the lines of https://mattstauffer.co/blog/enabling-gzip-on-nginx-servers-including-laravel-forge

Comment: @ChristianFazzini please, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323996/http-compression-in-rails-not-working-for-json-responses

Answer (score 5):

You can query Curl by setting a custom header to get gzipped response

```
$ curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" localhost:3000/posts.json > posts_json.gz
```

then, then decompress it to view the actual response json

```
 $ gzip -d posts_json.gz
 $ cat posts_json
```

If it doesn't work. post back with output of `rake middlewares` to help us troubleshoot further.

Comment: Along with the headers I also had to add 'config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater' to the app's application.rb file for it to actually compress the file.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can consider to write huge response into a file and gzip it:

```
res = {} # huge data hash
json = res.to_json

Zlib::GzipWriter.open('public/api/huge_data.json.gz') { |gz| gz.write json }
```

and update this file regularly

Comment: Compression is working fine but how to send this data to client as the api response.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

### Consider not putting Rack middlewares in `config.ru` when using Rails

Rails has it's own middleware stack manager since [Rails 2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/rails_on_rack.html#adding-a-middleware).

The correct way is:

```rb
# config/application.rb or config/environment.rb depends on your Rails version
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
```

### Don't use @djcp's solution when using `Rack::ETag`

Short answer:

```rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.insert_before Rack::ETag, Rack::Deflater
  end
end
```

The order of `Rack::Deflater` and `Rack::ETag` matters because `Rack::Deflater` uses [`Zlib::GzipWriter` to compress the response body](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/2d69212/lib/rack/deflater.rb#L94) and it would compress with a timestamp by default, which means the compressed response body would change every second even if the original response body is the same.

To reproduce this problem, run the following script:

```rb
require 'rack/etag'
require 'rack/deflater'
require 'rack/content_length'

@app = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rack::ETag
  use Rack::Deflater
  use Rack::ContentLength
  run ->(*) { [200, {}, ['hello world']] }
end

def puts_etag
  puts @app.call({ 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip' })[1]['ETag']
end

puts_etag
sleep 1
puts_etag
```

One can simply swap the lines of `Rack::ETag` and `Rack::Deflater` and get the expected output.

[Rails uses `Rack::ETag` by default](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/rails_on_rack.html#inspecting-middleware-stack) and `config.middleware.use` is just appending. To insert `Rack::Deflater` before `Rack::Etag`, use `config.middleware.insert_before` instead.