# Send the compressed json data from Ruby on Rails to android app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am requesting apis from android to get the json data . Is there a way to send the compressed json data to Android app ?
Right now we are using the below code to send the data

```
render :json => @rules
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766859/rails-json-response-with-gzip-compression

Will this help?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by compressed json data? You can gzip compress your response on apache/nginx layer.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule