# HTTP-Compression in rails not working for JSON-responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, nginx, http-compression

I have rails 3.2.1 application and nginx.

In nginx configurations I set `gzip on;`, and compressing works for pages, css, js files.

But it does not work for JSON responses. As I found the solution for rails is to add: `config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater` into application.rb.

And it helps: before response was 45Kb, now near 8Kb.

But, now I found that compression works only in Mac Chrome, Mac Firefox and Windows Chrome.

For IE 10, IE 11 and Windows Firefox - it does not work:

- I see `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` in request-header,
- I don't see `Content-Encoding: gzip` in response-header,
- response size is still 45Kb.

Please, help.

Comment: probably you just need to modify `gzip_types` to include `application/json`

Comment: @AlexeyTen But why it works only on Mac and Chrome?)))

Comment: @AlexeyTen do I need to `config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater` in application.rb after adding `application/json` to `gzip/types`?

Comment: I think, you don', cause nginx will do gzipping

Comment: You can compress response on backend then Nginx will not try to gzip it again if you have *proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip";* but of course Nginx provide a way better compression configuration. So Alexey Ten right, don't compress on Ruby side, let Nginx handle that

Comment: @mikhailov many thanks, additionally - don't hesitate to edit my my answer if you see something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by moving compressing configurations from rails to nginx configs.
I added to `<my_site>.conf`:

```
      # Enable Gzip
      gzip  on;
      gzip_http_version 1.0;
      gzip_comp_level 2;
      gzip_min_length 1100;
      gzip_buffers     4 8k;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml;

      gzip_static on;

      gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
      gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
      gzip_vary           on;
```

Thanks @Alexey Ten for help.

It works, but compressing are not visible in IE.
Some security programs on Windows catch "gzipped" HTTP-responses, extract it from archive, check for viruses and also remove `Content-Encoding: gzip` from header of response. IE as usual excelled :)